# How to write jquery functions inside define with requirejs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs

Help!!

When i write jquery function inside define its throwing error like:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( 

    define(['angular'],function($){
       $("#cmdLogin").click({
        validate();
       });  
    });
```

// CONFIGURATION LOOKS LIKE THIS:

```
 requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "assets/js",       
    paths: {
        jquery:'vendors/jquery/version/1.11.1/jquery.min',          
        bootstrap:[
                    'vendors/bootstrap/version/3.2/bootstrap.min',
                    'vendors/bootstrap/others/docs.min',
                    'vendors/bootstrap/others/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround',
                    'vendors/bootstrap/others/ie-emulation-modes-warning'
                  ]
    },
    shim: {

        'bootstrap': {
                        deps:['jquery','jqueryui']
                     }
    }       
});
```

What am i doing wrong, Please help how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid JavaScript:

```
$("#cmdLogin").click({
  validate();
});
```

You forgot the `function()` bit:

```
$("#cmdLogin").click(function() {
  validate();
});
```

...and you should be importing 'jquery', not 'angular', too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `angular` it should be `jquery`.

```
define(['jquery'],function($){
       $("#cmdLogin").click({
        validate();
       });  
    });
```